# Openldap v2.5: Synchronization between GroupofNames member and memberOf user attribute is not working

Tags: synchronization, ldap, openldap, memberof

I have openldap v2.5.15 installed:

```
slapd/jammy-updates,now 2.5.15+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed]
```

MemberOf and refint seems to be correctly added to my schema :

```
my@host:~$ ldapsearch -xLLL -b cn=config -D "uid=ldap_admin,ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=local"

dn: olcOverlay={1}memberof,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcConfig
objectClass: top
objectClass: olcMemberOf
olcOverlay: {1}memberof
olcMemberOfRefInt: TRUE
olcMemberOfGroupOC: groupOfNames
olcMemberOfMemberAD: member
olcMemberOfMemberOfAD: memberOf

dn: olcOverlay={2}refint,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcConfig
objectClass: top
objectClass: olcRefintConfig
olcOverlay: {2}refint
```

I'm adding a member "`uid=testmemberof,ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=local`" to my group "`cn=testgroupofnames,ou=groups,dc=mydomain,dc=local`"which has "`groupOfNames`" objectClass as needed:

```
dn: cn=testgroupofnames,ou=groups,dc=mydomain,dc=local
cn: testgroupofnames
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
structuralObjectClass: groupOfNames
entryUUID: b3317484-c628-103d-8846-457d724f70d3
creatorsName: uid=ldap_admin,ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=local
createTimestamp: 20230803090556Z
member: uid=testmemberof,ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=local
entryCSN: 20230803092934.468186Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: uid=ldap_admin,ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=local
modifyTimestamp: 20230803092934Z
```

I'm expecting the attribute memberOf to be added to my user "`uid=testmemberof,ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=local`", as [official_v2.5_ldap_docs](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin25/guide.html#Reverse%20Group%20Membership%20Maintenance) stated but nothing happens:

```
dn: uid=testmemberof,ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=local
mail: test@member.of
gidNumber: 10001
cn: test memberof
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: ldapPublicKey
loginShell: /bin/bash
userPassword:: my_hash_salted_password
uid: testmemberof
sshPublicKey: ssh-rsa random-data
gecos: test memberof
uidNumber: 10087
homeDirectory: /home/testmemberof
givenName: test
sn: memberof
structuralObjectClass: inetOrgPerson
entryUUID: ec8bd582-c62b-103d-8847-457d724f70d3
creatorsName: uid=ldap_admin,ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=local
createTimestamp: 20230803092900Z
entryCSN: 20230803092900.883040Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: uid=ldap_admin,ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=local
modifyTimestamp: 20230803092900Z
```

Would you please explain to me where is my mistake ?
Could it be objectClass that I defined in my user ? Like posixAccount or other stuff